# How can I add primary key and check constraint in (order_no) same column in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table sales_order 
(
     order_no varchar(6) constraint sales_pri PRIMARY KEY, 
     client_no varchar(6) constraint sales_ref_client 
          REFERENCES client_master (client_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
     order_date date not null, 
     delt_addr varchar(25), 
     salesman_no varchar(6) constraint sales_ref_sels 
         REFERENCES salesman_master(salesman_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,   
     dely_type char(1) DEFAULT 'F' check(dely_type in('P','F')), 
     bill_yn char(1), 
     dely_date date, 
     order_state varchar(10) constraint sales_state_ch check (order_state in('IN PROCESS','FULFILLED','BACKORDER','CANCELLED')), 
     constraint so_date check(order_date<dely_date)
)
```

Comment: I see what your asking...but can you put it into some context?

Comment: In Oracle we use `varchar2`, not `varchar` or `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you said *what* would that check constraint "check" ... for this example, I'm just checking whether order_no is `> '0'` (doesn't make much sense, though).

Also, not related to your question, but - you'd rather use `VARCHAR2` datatype (instead of `VARCHAR`). Why? Oracle recommends so.

---

Anyway, two options: outline constraint (just like your `so_date`) (see line #23):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE sales_order(
  2    order_no     VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_pri PRIMARY KEY,
  3    client_no    VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_client
  4                              REFERENCES client_master(client_no)
  5                              ON DELETE CASCADE,
  6    order_date   DATE NOT NULL,
  7    delt_addr    VARCHAR(25),
  8    salesman_no  VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_sels
  9                              REFERENCES salesman_master(salesman_no)
 10                              ON DELETE CASCADE,
 11    dely_type    CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK(dely_type IN('P', 'F')),
 12    bill_yn      CHAR(1),
 13    dely_date    DATE,
 14    order_state  VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT sales_state_ch
 15                               CHECK(order_state IN(
 16                                                    'IN PROCESS',
 17                                                    'FULFILLED',
 18                                                    'BACKORDER',
 19                                                    'CANCELLED'
 20                                                  )),
 21    CONSTRAINT so_date     CHECK(order_date < dely_date),
 22    --
 23    CONSTRAINT ch_order_no CHECK (order_no > '0')
 24  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Or, by altering the table:

```
SQL> DROP TABLE sales_order;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE sales_order(
  2    order_no     VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_pri PRIMARY KEY,
  3    client_no    VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_client
  4                              REFERENCES client_master(client_no)
  5                              ON DELETE CASCADE,
  6    order_date   DATE NOT NULL,
  7    delt_addr    VARCHAR(25),
  8    salesman_no  VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_sels
  9                              REFERENCES salesman_master(salesman_no)
 10                              ON DELETE CASCADE,
 11    dely_type    CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK(dely_type IN('P', 'F')),
 12    bill_yn      CHAR(1),
 13    dely_date    DATE,
 14    order_state  VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT sales_state_ch
 15                               CHECK(order_state IN(
 16                                                    'IN PROCESS',
 17                                                    'FULFILLED',
 18                                                    'BACKORDER',
 19                                                    'CANCELLED'
 20                                                  )),
 21    CONSTRAINT so_date     CHECK(order_date < dely_date)
 22  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE sales_order ADD CONSTRAINT ch_order_no CHECK (order_no > '0');

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Littlefoot notes you can add the CHECK constraint as an out-of-line constraint, as shown above. However, you can ALSO choose to add it as an inline constraint, as shown here:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_order(
     order_no     VARCHAR(6)
       CONSTRAINT sales_pri
         PRIMARY KEY
           USING INDEX
       CONSTRAINT ch_order_no
         CHECK (order_no > '0'),
     client_no    VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_client
                               REFERENCES client_master(client_no)
                               ON DELETE CASCADE,
     order_date   DATE NOT NULL,
     delt_addr    VARCHAR(25),
     salesman_no  VARCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT sales_ref_sels
                               REFERENCES salesman_master(salesman_no)
                               ON DELETE CASCADE,
     dely_type    CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F' CHECK(dely_type IN('P', 'F')),
     bill_yn      CHAR(1),
     dely_date    DATE,
     order_state  VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT sales_state_ch
                                CHECK(order_state IN(
                                                     'IN PROCESS',
                                                     'FULFILLED',
                                                     'BACKORDER',
                                                     'CANCELLED'
                                                   )),
     CONSTRAINT so_date     CHECK(order_date < dely_date)
   );
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e24a20d4e162f44f6aabd7596e4ab4f)